# 'module' object has no attribute 'py' when running from cmd

Tags: python, unit-testing, cmd

I'm currently learning unittesting, and I have stumbled upon a strange error:

If I run my script from inside PyCharm, everything works perfectly. If I run it from my `cmd.exe` (as administrator), I get the following error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import unittest

class TutorialUnittest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(23,23)
        self.assertNotEqual(11,12)

# function for raising errors.
def test_raise(self):
    with self.assertRaises(Exception):
        raise Exception`
```

Comment: Just try to remove the `.py` extension.

Comment: Is the trailing backtick a typo, or in your code (after Exception on the last line)?

Comment: @cdarke it is the original printscreen. I did not modify anythin.

Comment: @MarAja it worked, but why? Shouldn't it be able to execute it, even with Python extension?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just remove the `.py` extension.

You are running your tests using the `-m` command-line flag. The Python documentation will tell you more about it, just check out this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).

In a word, the `-m` option let you run a module, in your case the `unittest` module. This module expect to receive a module path or a class path following the Python format for module path (using dots). For example, if you want to run the FirstTest class in the mytests module in a mypackage folder you would use the following command line:

```
python -m unittest mypackage.mytests.FirstTest
```

Assuming that you are running the previous command line from the parent folder of mypackage. This allows you to select precisely the tests you want to run (even inside a module).

When you add the `.py` extension, `unittest` is looking for a `py` object (like a module or a class) inside the last element of the module path you gave but, yet this object does not exist. This is exactly what your terminal error tells:

```
AttributeError: ’module’ object has no attribute ’py’
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add at the bottom of your script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Then you can run `python test_my_function.py` normally