# Unittest is giving AttributeError: module 'tests.test_example' has no attribute 'py'

Tags: python

I'm using an Anaconda environment and getting the error in the title. This error occurs for any of my unit tests.

My first intuition is that python is not working in the environment, but typing "python" or "py" starts the Python console as expected.

Comment: Is it possible you're using `python -m` but including the `.py` from the module's filename? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527284/module-object-has-no-attribute-py-when-running-from-cmd

Comment: Ugh you're correct, such a simple mistake. Thank you!